# Fill in the blanks with appropriate modalsI

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

***Use appropriate modals to fill in the blanks:***

1) It is a good book you _____ read it.

2) He _____ not come today because it is raining.

3) I would do it if I _____.

4) We ____ stamp a letter before posting it.

5) He said that he _____ go to Bombay next week.

6) The doctor says that you _____ give up smoking at once.

7) We ______ sign our name at the end of letter.

8) The girls ______ wear Sarees if they wish to.

9) Since your handwriting is good, you ____ write the certificates.

10) You ____ ask a question, if you please.

11) If you practice well you ____ be selected in the team.

12) It ____ rain in the evening today.

13) A man ____ eat to live.

***My answers:***

1) should

2) may

3) could

4) should

5) would

6) should

7) should

8) may

9) can

10) may

11) would

12) may

13) must

*Somebody please check my answers.*

These questions are a part of exercise containing 31 questions.

Comment: Since I am new so I don’t what details I have to provide in the question. I would add the other details if someone asks me to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several of these sentences could have more than one right answer, depending on the nuance you wished to convey.

9) I would choose should.  "You should be the one to write the certificates, because your handwriting is good."

11) I think "could" is the better choice.  "Could" leaves open the option that the coach might not pick you no matter how well you played. "Would" implies that you will definitely be selected, which might not be the case.

10 & 12) "could" is ok too in the USA, but less formal than "may."